# "WFLYJCA0041: Failed to load module for driver [com.mysql]" on Jboss 7 with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I am creating a web application for JBoss EAP 7 and trying to connect to `MySQL 8.0` database.

Am getting the error as

> [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "datasources"),
>           ("jdbc-driver" => "mysql")]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0041: Failed to load module for driver [com.mysql]"

```
My module.xml file in \jboss-eap-7.1.0\modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\main is as follows:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-8.0.12" />
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>

And placed "mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar" in \jboss-eap-7.1.0\modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\main path where module.xml exist.
```

Datasource configuraion is:

```
<datasources>
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/sdmspool" pool-name="sdmspool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://database;databaseName = sdms</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql-connector-java-8.0.12</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>user</user-name>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="mysql-connector-java-8.0.12" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
```

Can anyone help me in solving this?

Comment: There is no such thing as Wildfly 7.  Wildfly 8 was the first Wildfly release.  You're running JBoss 7.  I updated the tags.

Comment: Are there any other errors further up in the logs?

Answer (score 8):

Try creating the module by using jboss-cli as follows:
Run the below commands:

- `./jboss-cli.sh` (this will start cli in disconnected mode,in the same mode run the below command)
- `module add --name=com.mysql --resources=/path/to/mysql.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api`
  and then try adding respective driver in your eap configuration.

You don't have to explicitly define `driver-class` and `xa-datasource-class`.

Comment: This way worked for me, I was trying to add the Redshift driver, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this configuration I was missing. Worked for me as well

Comment: This is the only right way of doing it, official documenation mentioning a method with manual addition of a module is misleading. The command-line function adds to `{base-url}\keycloak-11.0.2\modules\com` folder directly (not `{base-url}\keycloak-11.0.2\modules\system\layers\keycloak\com`).

Answer (score 1):

resource root path should be as well mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar

please note that the extension (.jar) is missing in your xml config